# What does it mean to "walk the wall?"

Tags: meaning, idioms

From the same people who brought us "ask" as a noun comes a new idiom that I haven't heard of before: to "walk the wall."

I haven't heard this myself, but my sister (who is an IT consultant) asked me what it means, which means that I will likely be subjected to this very soon as well.

My speculative guess is that it means to try to get an idea of the scope of a problem by "walking" around it at a high level, but I have no idea as I haven't heard it in context.

Comment: Are you sure it might not have been [walk the walk](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/walk-the-walk.html)?

Comment: In what context has she heard it? I would guess it is akin to "walking the perimeter," which refers to patrolling territorial boundaries and can be used in an IT security context.

Comment: hmmm.  Urban dictionary has an interesting definition for "walk the wall".  What has your research borne out, @fluffy?

Comment: @Jon: The first couple of instances [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22walk+the+wall%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22walk+the+wall%22&hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&sa=X&ei=xp8SUfrtLOGm0QW9gYGAAQ&ved=0CCUQpwUoAQ&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41934586,d.d2k&fp=ca26872ec34c7bf0&biw=1247&bih=875) seem to be for OP's usage (which I'd never heard of before).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you may well have the answer.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: ELU helpfully hung on to the answer text I was drafting before I broke off to have my tea, but Carolyn's link seems to have nailed it anyway.

Comment: My sister just emailed me again: "okay - so it's essentially a deep dive on process flow. But noone knew that! what dumb waste of time."

Comment: @KristinaLopez My sister mentioned the UD definition when she was trying to figure it out. PRETTY SURE that's not the usage she's asking about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Walk the Wall" can refer to a kind of Stand-Up meeting in which the group goes through each item of work in their "wall" and talks about its progress.

http://fabiopereira.me/blog/2011/02/28/walk-the-wall-stand-up-meeting/

Comment: Looks good to me. *Wallboard, wall chart, flipchart, story board, status board* are standard terminology in the management "show and tell" game, and the guy who has to stand up and explain what it all means is as likely to *walk* through it as *talk* it through.

Comment: My sister got a partial answer from some of her clients that it was "essentially a deep dive on process flow." I'm not sure that definition quite matches up with yours. But who knows what any of this management-speak lingo means anymore.

Comment: What does this mean? : 
"essentially a deep dive on process flow."

Comment: @FacebookAnswers Exactly!

Answer (score 2):

*Walk the wall* is a military term for "guard a border, watch those on the outside, keep those on the inside safe".

Answer (score 2):

Walk the wall is used by various consultants for reviewing internal ops/workflow/org structures. Each leaders has assigned workflow and review it all during a "walk the wall" session - literally walking thru the workflow.

Answer (score -1):

You've misheard the phrase ;it is " walk the walk " .It  is used to show approval and it means to actually do something rather than just talking about it, so that people can see you really are good at it.

For example :

Children really do listen to their parents, especially if the parents walk the walk and not just talk the talk.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/walk-the-walk

Comment: I have not misheard anything, and I verified with my sister (who was asking the question of me) that she did not mishear this either. See the comments on the OP.